# Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null' in FutureBuilder SnapShot Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new in FLutter and try to get some JSON data and show it in a List. When I tried to connect to the APi, it works just fine, and I got the JSON response from the server. But when I try to show it in the list with FutureBuilder, it says that the snapshot returns null, even thought the response from the data is exist.
This is the JSON response that I got from the server

```
{
            "error_code"     : "00",
            "error_message"  : "Success",
            "user_list"       : 
            [
                {
                    "name"   : "Swift",
                    "user_id": "2048"
                }, {
                    "name"   : "Python",
                    "user_id": "1024"
                }, {
                    "name"   : "Objective-C",
                    "user_id": "512"
                }, {
                    "name"   : "Ruby",
                    "user_id": "256"
                }
            ]
        }
```

This is my get method, because I only want to use the `user_list` field, I try to filter it this way.

```
Future<List<Patient>> getPatient() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url+"/interns"));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        print(data['user_list']);
        return List<Patient>.from(data['user_list'].map((item)=>Patient.fromJson(item)));
    } else {
        throw Exception("Failed");
    }
  }
```

This is the FutureBuilder that throw the error

```
FutureBuilder<List<Patient>>(
                future: patientService.getPatient(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasError) {
                      print(snapshot);
                      return Center(
                        child: Text("Error"),
                      );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData){
                      List<Patient> patients = snapshot.data;
                      return _buildListView(patients);
                  } else {
                      return Center(
                      child: Container(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

And this is the patient model class

```
Patient({required this.name, required this.userId});

    factory Patient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
      return Patient(
          name    :json['name'],
          userId  : json['userId']
      );
    }
```

This is my error

```
AsyncSnapshot<List<Patient>>(ConnectionState.done, null, Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'
```

Comment: Try to add **AsyncSnapshot<List>** on builder

Comment: I would suggest you use `try-catch` in `getPatient` method.

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil sorry, its not working

Comment: @JohnJoe thank you for your suggestion, but it pass the try block, so I think the problem is in the FutureBuilder.

Comment: wrap `try-catch` in `List<Patient>.from(data['user_list'].map((item)=>Patient.fromJson(item)));`. and see

Comment: @JohnJoe yeah, looks like it have an error in this block, it return `Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'`

Comment: @JohnJoe `[{name: Swift, user_id: 2048}, {name: Python, user_id: 1024}, {name: Objective-C, user_id: 512}, {name: Ruby, user_id: 256}]`

Comment: @JohnJoe it give this error `AsyncSnapshot<List<Patient>>(ConnectionState.done, null, Expected a value of type 'FutureOr<List<Patient>>', but got one of type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>'`

Comment: @JohnJoe oh sorry, I forget to add it. It still give the error `AsyncSnapshot<List<Patient>>(ConnectionState.done, null, Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'`

Comment: Perhaps should be `json['user_id ']` instead of `json['userId']` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Oh thanks! it worked now. Didn't notice it until now.

Comment: I will delete the previous comment as it is misleading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`json['user_id ']` instead of `json['userId']`. The parameter name is different, that's why you are getting Null error.

Answer (score 0):

As John mentioned in this post, to fix your code you need to use `user_id` when parsing the `Patient` data.

However, not sure if you fixed this issue in your code already, but the code that you shared with end up making a many extra calls to your endpoint because you are creating your Future `getPatient` in a Build method. If you put a breakpoint in your code, it should be called at least 3 times on a first app reload.

You should store the Future in a local variable and reference that in the `FutureBuilder`. This is a [very common problem](https://jup.dev/how-to-use-flutterbuilder-properly-and-common-mistakes/) that I see people make and I also did this problem in the past.